# Error al enviar correo desde ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net

Este es mi codigo : Intento poner cualquier correo y me sale el siguiente error

```
protected void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNombre.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtApellido.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtdni.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtcelular.Text))
            {
                danger.Visible = true;
                succes.Visible = false;
                LimpiarCampo();
            }
            else
            {
                RegistrarAfiliados();
                SendMail(txtNombre.Text, txtEmail.Text);
                LimpiarCampo();
                danger.Visible = false;
                succes.Visible = true;

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

    }

    protected void SendMail(string NomAfiliado,string email)
    {
        StringBuilder emailHtml = new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("Enlace/enlace.html")));
        emailHtml.Replace("[%var_Afiliado%]", NomAfiliado);
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(email);
        message.To.Add(email);
        message.Subject = "Afiliación de Conductores";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = emailHtml.ToString();

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
        smtpClient.Port = 25;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("tucorreo@outlook.com","tucontraseña**");
        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
```

Imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: para el host `smtp.office365.com` ya intentaste tbn con el puerto **587**, verificaste que el puerto **25** no esta bloqueado. Algunos firewalls de red o ISP bloquean puertos, especialmente el puerto 25.

Comment: acabo de intentar con el puerto 587 , pero me sale el mismo error .

Comment: podrias usar: smtp-mail.outlook.com y el puerto 587

Comment: referencia: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040

Comment: Lo mas extraño es que solo envia el correo , con una cuenta , pero cuando cambio me sale el mismo error , ya hice lo que me dijiste y tampoco estimado .

Comment: a que te refieres con: **`solo envia el correo , con una cuenta`**, te refieres que logras enviar correo con una cuenta en especifico

Comment: exacto solo puedo enviar con un solo correo , pero no puedo con otros.

Comment: El correo que le pasas a **`message.From`** debe ser el mismo que utilizas en **`smtpClient.Credentials`** si son diferente no te funcionara. Bueno eso es lo que he visto en los ejemplos que hay en la red, o quizas este equivocado. Has la prueba.